# Does Level One Purity protect colonists as well as explorers?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

So I'm leveling the purity path and I like that level one protects my explorers. This  makes me wonder, does this also protect my colonists as well?

Answer (score 8):

The level 1 Purity perk will prevent aliens from attacking a tile containing an Explorer - unfortunately Colonists do not inherit this bonus, and are still vulnerable.

However, if you stack an Explorer on top of your Colonist (which is possible as Explorers are military units, whereas Colonists are civilians,) aliens will fear the Explorer and won't attack. A viable strategy might be for the two units to travel together - with the Explorer protecting the colonist until they plant an outpost, and then exploring the surrounding area once it's down.

EDIT: The question and answer above refer to an earlier version of the game; the Level 1 Purity perk no longer prevents aliens from attacking explorers. Instead, it gives explorers better defense against aliens, so the advice of stacking an explorer on a colonist is still viable - however, it may be preferable to stack a military unit on the colonist instead.

[Source](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Purity_%28CivBE%29)